# How to skip parskip linespread for all chapter definitions?

Tags: spacing, chapters, parskip

I'm trying to skip my `parskip` and `linespread` settings for all of my `\chapter` definitions.

Here's my complete example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\inputencoding{utf8}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\chapter{Der positive Wandel – von den Neunzigern bis Heute}
\label{derpositivewandelvondenneunzigernbisheute}

The next paragraph starts.

\end{document}
```

… and the compiled output:

[image: example]

… what I want is a spacing like this:

[image: ideal]

### Here's a list of my failed attempts

What all of these have in common is that they are not the solution or that I applied them completely in the wrong way.

I tried to rewrite the chapter via `\renewcommand` but failed… obviously something went wrong.

Inspired by [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112312/parskip-suppressing-parskip-in-some-places) I also tried `\newcommand\chapter[1]{\par#1\par\vspace{-\parskip}}` which was as faulty as the one above.

My next try was [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58619/how-to-avoid-parskip-being-applied-to-listoffigures-etc):

```
\newcommand\std@startsection{}
\let\std@startsection\@startsection
\def\@startsection{\renewcommand*\baselinestretch{1}\std@startsection}
```

Again, it didn't work. Just like this didn't work:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}
  {\chapter{lof}}
  {\chapter{loa}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}\chapter{lof}}
  {}{}
\makeatother
```

Or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59593/parskip-stretches-more-than-expected):

```
\renewcommand\chapter
{\vspace{1.725\baselineskip plus 3\baselineskip minus .192\baselineskip }}
```

Comment: Do *not* use the »[parskip](http://ctan.org/pkg/parskip)« package. Read about the `parskip` option for the document class in the »[KOMA-Script](http://texdoc.net/pkg/koma-script)« user guide and give it a corresponding value. For the inter-line spacing use the »[setspace](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace)« package and read something about "deadly sins" in »[l2tabu](http://texdoc.net/pkg/l2tabu-english)«.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to patch `\chapter` or `\@makechapterhead`. Simply add your command to the font command:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,parskip=half-]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\usepackage{setspace,lipsum}
\doublespacing %to see better the difference

\makeatletter
\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\setstretch{\setspace@singlespace}} 
%or only chapter instead of sectioning
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Der positive Wandel – von den Neunzigern bis Heute}
\label{derpositivewandelvondenneunzigernbisheute}

{\Huge\bfseries\sffamily Der positive Wandel – von den Neunzigern bis Heute\par}

\lipsum[1]The next paragraph starts.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

`setspace` is the best solution for manipulating the linespread (see also @ThorstenDonigs comments). The following solution patches `\@makechapterhead` relying on `setspace`s `\singlespacing` macro.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \inputencoding{utf8}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
  \onehalfspacing
\let\KOMA@makechapterhead\@makechapterhead
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
\begingroup
\singlespacing
\KOMA@makechapterhead{#1}
\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Der positive Wandel – von den Neunzigern bis Heute}
\label{derpositivewandelvondenneunzigernbisheute}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution (which by the way also worked). I read on parskip in the provided link by Thorsten but I guess I'll have to dive into LaTeX a bit more before I fully comprehend it (I just started three days ago). I choose Ulrike's version because it felt more concise.